# ActiveRecord store attribute in rails 4.2 breaking on serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, store

I am upgrading a Rails 3 project to Rails 4 and it is breaking on one of my models that uses an [ActiveRecord Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) property. My model looks like the following:

```
class ModelClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :attr_1, ..., attr_n, as: :admin

    store :properties, accessors: [:attr_1, ..., :attr_n], coder: JSON
end
```

The `:properties` field is a text field in Postgres.

And when I try to access the data in this model I get the following `JSON::ParserError`:

```
795: unexpected token at '{"attr_1"=>"", ..., "attr_n"=>""}'
```

These records were all created in Rails 3, and before upgrading to Rails 4 my model class did not have `coder: JSON` at the end of the `store` call. It looks like the data in the database is not being serialized correctly does anyone have any idea why and how to fix it? Is it because my data looks like a ruby hash with the `=>` hash rocket in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the JSON parser fails because the string isn't a json.

You could fix your records by evaluating the string and converting it to json afterwards. `eval` is to be used carefully but if this is a one time job then you could probably run something like this in the `rails console`.

```
ModelClass.all.each do |m|
  m.properties = eval(m.properties).to_json
  m.save
end
```

Not tested, please try on one record before updating your entire table.

Comment: Will it still be stored as text in the db? And when I add new records will they now be stored in correct json format?

Comment: it will be stored as text yes. If you are able to use a json data type on the database level as mu suggested then it'll be better (and you won't need the `store` serialisation but `store_accessor` to read the data)

Comment: I'm guessing that this won't work because `ModelClass` will try to parse `properties` as JSON as it loads each row. I think you'd need to bypass the model completely and do the format conversion by hand using direct database calls.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do either of you know of a good way to do this in Rails as I'm doing my upgrade to 4.2? (@muistooshort you are right this doesn't work)

Comment: sorry I was away. Couldn't you temporarily specify properties as a regular attribute instead of a store in the model, so you can do the update ?